# Conjugate momenta in Radial Quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, momentum, conformal-field-theory, commutator

When we radially quantize a conformal field theory, is there at least formally a notion of a conjugate momentum $\Pi$ to the primary fields $O$ which would satisfy an equal radius commutation relation $$[O(\Omega), \Pi(\Omega\,')] = i\hbar\hat{\bf 1}\sqrt{g}\delta^{d-1}(\Omega-\Omega\,')$$
where $\Omega$ are the hyperspherical coordinates on the constant $r$ surface and $g$ is the spherical metric? In the case of a massless free scalar field, we could explicitly compute this conjugate field in terms of radial derivatives, but I have never seen this talked about in the context of a general CFT. Is it that you can't actually construct such an operator or is it just that it's not particularly useful?

Comment: Radial quantization is done in Euclidean signature where all operators commute at spacelike distances, so the commutation relations are sort of trivial.

Comment: If I'm thinking about a path integral, that's valid when I do the path integral over the entire spacetime, but if I am doing a path integral over a disc, say, for state preparation, then the radial ordering becomes important. Same with Euclidean time ordering and time sliced manifolds. Then canonical commutation relations are non-trivial even in Euclidean signature I believe.

Comment: This is what happens in stochastic integrals (i.e. Euclidean path integrals), see for example this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350614/whats-the-role-of-commutation-relations-in-stochastic-mechanics